# How to get Finder sidebar favorites content cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, finder

I need to get paths of objects displayed in Favorites section of Finder Sidebar (for current user). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting the shared file list is only the first part, you still may want to get an actual string object with your path.  Here is a little code snippet that will let you get a path for each object in the favorites section of the finder sidebar.

```
UInt32 seed;
LSSharedFileListRef sflRef = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL,
                                                    kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems,
                                                    NULL);
CFArrayRef items = LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot( sflRef, &seed );
for( size_t i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(items); i++ )
{
    LSSharedFileListItemRef item = (LSSharedFileListItemRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, i);
    if( !item )
        continue;
    CFURLRef outURL = NULL;
    LSSharedFileListItemResolve( item, kLSSharedFileListNoUserInteraction, (CFURLRef*) &outURL, NULL );
    if( !outURL )
        continue;
    //The actual path string of the item
    CFStringRef itemPath = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath(outURL,kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle);
    // TODO: Do whatever you want to do with your path here!!!!
    CFRelease(outURL);
    CFRelease(itemPath);
}
CFRelease(items);
CFRelease(sflRef);
```

Comment: Be aware that since macOS Monterey LSSharedFileListItemResolve() will trigger the display of a TCC permission dialog for Desktop, Downloads and Documents folders, the first time it is run and no permissions were granted previously to the app.

Answer (score 4):

There's not a Cocoa API, per se.  You would use the LSSharedFileList API.  The API is public but the only documentation is the header file, /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Headers/LSSharedFileList.h.  You want the `kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems` (and maybe `kLSSharedFileListFavoriteVolumes`) list type(s).

Comment: Can you write code example? I'm not sure I understand how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LSSharedFileList` API(LaunchServices/LSSharedFileList.h.)

```
 LSSharedFileListRef favoriteItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL,
                                                            kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems, NULL);
```