# How to get current user's default movie directory and other default directories?

Tags: macos

As the title mentioned. In OS X, How can I get current pathes for user's "FAVORITES" directories on the left?

[image]

Also, it will be a great help if you guys also tell me that what documents is my question releted to. Thank you at advance!

Comment: You should check the path under /Users 
ex. /Users/user_name/Music/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get access to common directories like Documents, Desktop, Movies, etc., `-[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory:inDomains:]` is the API you're looking for. You'll want to use the `NSUserDomainMask` for the domains parameter and one of the `NSSearchPathDirectory` constants (like `NSMoviesDirectory`) for the directory parameter.

If you're actually trying to get the list of folders the current user has in the "Favorites" section of their Finder sidebar (users can customize this list), [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751199/how-to-get-finder-sidebar-favorites-content-cocoa) may have some answers for you.

Comment: The link you gave fit my purpose. Thank you!!