# How to access finder sidebar shared content in cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, shared-libraries, finder

I want to access the shared content of left sidebar of finder in mac, so that i can get the system list connected to the same network. I can access favorite content, but could not get succeeded to access.

I am using this code to access favorite content of finder.

```
UInt32 seed;
LSSharedFileListRef sflRef = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL,
                                                    kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems,
                                                    NULL);
CFArrayRef items = LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot( sflRef, &seed );
for( size_t i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(items); i++ )
{
    LSSharedFileListItemRef item = (LSSharedFileListItemRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, i);
    if( !item )
        continue;
    CFURLRef outURL = NULL;
    LSSharedFileListItemResolve( item, kLSSharedFileListNoUserInteraction, (CFURLRef*) &outURL, NULL );
    if( !outURL )
        continue;
    //The actual path string of the item
    CFStringRef itemPath = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath(outURL,kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle);
    // TODO: Do whatever you want to do with your path here!!!!
    CFRelease(outURL);
    CFRelease(itemPath);
}
CFRelease(items);
CFRelease(sflRef);


Since i want to access systems available in shared network i change the key according to the key in the header file
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.fram‌​ework/Headers/LSSharedFileList.h

```
But i get nothing for shared content.

Can anyone help me for accessing this.
Thanks for your time to help me in advance.
```

Comment: Any coding attempted ?

Comment: yes i get favorites content by using info from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751199/how-to-get-finder-sidebar-favorites-content-cocoa but any key available in the /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Headers/LSSharedFileList.h header file does not give info about shared content

Comment: Show your codes in the question please

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kLSSharedFileListRecentServerItems` to get Recently connected network volumes.